# Multiple values appear as a single entry in the lotus notes view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I have an issue with a lotus notes view. This view displays entries based on the number of problems in the field "All problems". This field is a multivalued field. In the view column properties for the column "problem", the multivalue separator is New line & under the sorting tab, the checkbox against "show multiple values as separate entries" is checked.  When i see the view from my machine, multiple values appear as a separate entry. When i checked in another machine, the view was displayed as expected. The problem came, when i tried to do a search for documents based on a value. Now the multiple values come as a single entry which is not supposed to happen. The strange thing is it appears fine in my machine. But when i tried it in another machine, i face the issue. To make sure its not a version problem i checked it in a machine with the same version as mine(8.5.3) also tried in a lower version(7.5) but got the same result.                                           I even tried the following:  1.delete the cache.ndk. 2. remove the DB icon from workspace and reopen the database from applications.  3. go to (Byurl) view in bookmark.nsf and delete all the documents and reopen lotus notes.  4.rebuild views using Ctrl+Shift+F9. Could not do a database rebuild(no access). Does any one know what can be the problem and possible resolutions?

Comment: I took a local copy of the DB in the same machine. I added the documents and used the same search criteria. But this time there were no issues. I took a copy of the template also, which is used to refresh the design of the DB and everything was fine. This confused me more, because i'm not sure if a design refresh will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search is returning a single document, which is correct. It's the representation of the document that is annoying you, you want to have it displayed as it was originally, i.e. with a categorized column. If you are sorting another column in the view, the categorized column gets turned off.

Have a look in Search in View/More/Sort Results by, that might be your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped. I was wondering why the sort was not being done as in the original form. I gave the search criteria directly without going into the "More" search features. Thanks again!!